# react-native run-android command not working

Tags: android, cmd, react-native, regedit, autorun

I am working on mobile apps using react native. Everything was working fine and I used to see my app in my simulator. Today I have attempted to change the default directory for the command prompt to my project directory so that I no need to do cd each time I open cmd prompt. Somehow it affected react native libraries and now I am not able to run -android on my machine. I have used below command to reset my default path.

```js
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v AutoRun /t REG_SZ /d "IF x"%COMSPEC%"==x%CMDCMDLINE% (cd /D F:\development\reactnative)"
```

Below is the screenshot of the issue for run-android command
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQs4J.png)

Below is the screenshot of reg folder. Currently, I have removed Autorun. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3VNX.png)

Can someone please help to undo this default directory change and reset to normal. I have searched a few solutions on google and tried but no use. I don't want to mess my system anymore. Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem got resolved after I reset my PC and reinstall the application.